# Inserting Values Multiple Times Using a Single Form Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I need to create a form in my rails3 application that, when saved, will validate the fields and then submit them. I need a row for each field essentially.

The reason for this is that each 'user' has multiple attributes. For example:

- User-Password
- Expiration
- Access-Group

Have tried a nested form but that doesn't really work for me.

In my console, this works pretty well for me:

```
user = Array.new
user << {:username => "jenny", :attribute_name => "User-Password", :value => "123"}
user << {:username => "jenny", :attribute_name => "Expiration", :value => "123"}
user << {:username => "jenny", :attribute_name => "Access-Group", :value => "123"}
User.create(user)
```

That inserts a number of rows, each with the same username but different attribute names and values. Perfect.

My problem is, how do I do this using a single form?? Initially I had a parent model and a nested form but I can't figure it out.

Comment: EAV seems extremely poorly suited for this task (and will always be an uphill battle in Rails). Is there a reason you're using EAV modeling instead of a table with columns?

Comment: am new to rails and wasn't sure what to do. looked also at this [link](http://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/) but still not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should actually be pretty straightforward nested form. Let us assume

```
class User
  has_many :attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :attributes, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end

class Attribute
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and an `Attribute` has an `attribute_name`, a `value` and a `user_id`.

Then your form, using haml, [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) and [cocoon](http://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) would look like

```
= simple_form_for @user do
  = f.input :name
  #attributes
    = f.simple_fields_for :attributes do |attribute|
      = render 'attribute_fields', :f => attribute
    .links
      = link_to_add_association 'add new attribute', f, :attributes
```

and you add a partial called `_attribute_fields.html.haml`

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :attribute_name
  = f.input :value
  = link_to_remove_association "remove attribute", f
```

If the attributes are fixed, you could easily change the input for `attribute_name` to

```
= f.input :attribute_name, :as => :select, :collection => {'User-Password', 'Expiration', 'Access-Group' }
```

If you want to read more about different types of nested forms, I have written a [blogpost](http://www.dixis.com/?p=561) about it in greater detail.

[EDIT] Adding server-side validation to `Attribute` model:

Inside class `Attribute` you need to add:

```
validate :check_valid_values

def check_valid_values
  if attribute_name == 'Expiration'
    errors.add(:value, "Must be a valid date for Expiration") unless value.is_a_valid_date?
  end
end
```

Note that the method `is_a_valid_date?` does not exist, this is just to provide a small example. In this validation method you would then add all the possible attribute-value combinations with their validation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thorough answer :) let me read thoroughly to understand it. J

Comment: That's very cool! Is it however possible to do some field validations as well. For example, if the attribute is set to expiration, it needs to check for correct date format...

Comment: Server side validation is as usual. Or do you mean javascript? Imho that is definitely possible, but not easy. When using such a free-form data format, you are making such things very hard for you. It has its use, when attributes need to be dynamic. But it comes with a price.

Comment: Was thinking server side but assume it's not possible with these dynamic attributes?

Comment: Serverside there is not problem at all. I added a small example for this.